# Specify maven install plugin version

Tags: maven, maven-install-plugin

I am using maven to build a project which requires java 1.6. But the building process uses maven-install-pluging version 3.0.0-M1 which is not compatible with java 1.6. I have not configured maven-install-plugin version anywhere in the project. How do I say to use maven-install-pluging version 2.4. I use maven 3.2.2 version

Comment: Of course it requires JDK 7 cause it's stated in the release notes https://www.mail-archive.com/announce@maven.apache.org/msg00873.html

Answer (score 1):

You can set the plugin version by defining it in `pluginManagement` section :

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
  ...
</build>
```